# Why am i getting an error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertAdjacentHTML' of null at renderHTML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ajax, rendering

How do I get my information to render and not display an error? I was following a video and I'm also having a few other console errors that may or may not be affecting it also.

```js
var bitprice = document.getElementById('bitprice');

$( document ).ready(function() {

    var bitcoin = new XMLHttpRequest();
    bitcoin.open('GET', "https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json");
    bitcoin.onload = function() {
        // console.log(bitcoin.responseText);
        var bitdata = JSON.parse(bitcoin.responseText);
        // console.log(bitdata.bpi.USD.rate);
        renderHTML(bitdata.bpi.USD.rate);
    };
    bitcoin.send();

});

function renderHTML(data) {
    bitprice.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',"test")
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Bitview</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %> (Inside the yield is as follows <div id="bitprice"></div>)
 <script type="text/javascript" src="app/assets/javascripts/js.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: why is `var bitprice` outside of the function that is using it? Try defining it inside the function and it should work. Note: this is not a rails bug, but javascript :) (Note: if this fixes your problem I'll turn it into an answer to accept, but lets try it first and see)

Comment: You are amazing it works. I'm learning thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why is `var bitprice` outside of the function that is using it? Try defining it inside the function and it should work.

There's a thing to learn about called "scope". The way javascript works - something outside the function might not be visible inside the function because of the way scope works. It's worth googling about for a good article or two.

Comment: Are you sure it is a scope issue rather than a timing issue? There might not be a `#bitprice` when the `getElementById` executes but there will be when everything is loaded (e.g. https://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/bbbL9xnh/3/). Moving the `bitprice` definition into `renderHTML` is the right move in either case.